# Downloading selected PDFs from CAG

Tags: pdf, web-scraping, download

I am trying to download some PDFs from CAG Website https://cag.gov.in/en/state-accounts-report?defuat_state_id=64. I need PDFs for only Monthly Key Indicators, so I am using the code as-

```
tabID="#tab-360"
for link in soup.select(f"{tabID} a[href$='.pdf']"):
  filename=os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
  with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
      f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url,link['href'])).content)
```

This allows me to download the Monthly key indicators file but I need to download only Pdf files from March 2018 to March 2022. How to download March PDFs from 2018 to 2022.

Answer (score 0):

The following code helped me in getting all march files

```
urllist=[]
url='https://cag.gov.in/en/state-accounts-report?defuat_state_id=79'
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select(f"{tabID} a[href$='.pdf']"):
urllist.append(link)

final_listMah=[]
list_year=['March, 2022','March(Pre), 2022','March(Pre), 2021','March, 2021','March(Pre), 2020','March(Pre), 2019','April, 2019']
for j in list_year:
 for i in range(len(urllist)):
  if (urllist[i].text==j):
   print(urllist[i])
   final_listMah.append(urllist[i])
```